# Terminal profile keeps losing mapped drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, terminal-services, mapped-drive, roaming-profiles

I have two users that keep losing their mapped drives on their Windows 2012 profiles. We have two terminal servers and they seem to lose it when they log into a specific one. Still trying to figure out which one it is. I have tried viewing each server and can't find anything that seems to be disconnected.

What could be causing them to lose their mapped drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use a shortcut that point to the network location. This way, each user only obtains the shortcuts they need.

Mapping drives, especially to drive letters, limits you. If you have two locations for the same drive letter, it will cause issues in the system.

I assume multiple users are signing in at once, being a terminal server environment.